# SharePoint 2010 - Single Sign-On on a claims web app WITHOUT a password, like SetAuthCookie()

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication, claims-based-identity

I’m working on a scenario that runs like this: user click a link in a SAP site that takes him/her to a SharePoint site. To accomplish single sign-on, an http module takes a SAP cookie, gets a username and logs user into SharePoint.

When implemented on SP 2007, it used to work: simply calling SetAuthCookie(username) did the work, user got to the SharePoint 2007 site and everything worked as expected.

When on a SharePoint 2010 claims web app, it stopped working. That’s pretty much expected, per [this great article from Steve Peschka](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/21/writing-a-custom-forms-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx). So I went ahead and started replacing the SetAuthCookie() code, but I’m facing two issues

Here’s my custom sign in code. Is there any equivalent to SetAuthCookie() that doesn't need a password? (nevermind hard-coded url’s and pwd’s... just a prototype)

```
private SPIisSettings IisSettings
{
    get
    {
        SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://virtualcasa1/sites/blank2"));//XXX
        SPIisSettings settings = webApp.IisSettings[SPUrlZone.Default];
        return settings;
    }
}

private SecurityToken GetSecurityToken()
{
    SecurityToken token = null;
    SPIisSettings iisSettings = IisSettings;
    Uri appliesTo = new Uri("http://virtualcasa1");//XXX

    SPFormsAuthenticationProvider authProvider = iisSettings.FormsClaimsAuthenticationProvider;
    token = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(appliesTo, authProvider.MembershipProvider, authProvider.RoleProvider, "userfba", "pa55word");//XXX
    return token;
}

private void SignIn()
{
    SecurityToken token = null;

    if ((token = GetSecurityToken()) != null)
    {
        SPFederationAuthenticationModule fam = SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current;
        HttpContext c = HttpContext.Current;
        fam.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(token);
        c.Response.Redirect("/sites/blank2");//XXX
    }
}

void OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext c = HttpContext.Current;
    if (c.Request.Url.ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Contains("/authenticate.aspx"))
    {
        SignIn();
    }
```

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to answer my own question (hate to answer myself, but sometimes that's the way it works...), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akirsman/archive/2012/05/09/custom-single-sign-on-scenario-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) are the details. Hope it helps someone, somewhere.